# Insert 1M rows to a dataframe using list append approach is too slow

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

I want to append around 1 million rows to a datafarme. Current approach is taking long time and is fissible. following is what i am doing:

Sample row to be appended in each iteration:

```
['Offer_5', 'Offer_4', 'Offer_12', 'Offer_8', 'Offer_10', 'Offer_2', 1000065]
```

Sample code as follows:

```
cols = ['OFFER_CODE_1','OFFER_CODE_2','OFFER_CODE_3','OFFER_CODE_4','OFFER_CODE_5','OFFER_CODE_6','ID']

final_lst_appened = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    final_lst = []
    #some processing to get a row as stated above
    final_lst_appened.append(final_lst)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data = final_lst_appened)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small performance bump may be to change `iterrows()` to `itertuples`, as described here: https://medium.com/swlh/why-pandas-itertuples-is-faster-than-iterrows-and-how-to-make-it-even-faster-bc50c0edd30d . Otherwise, if the code in the for-loop where you generate each row is computationally heavy, you may want to look into multiprocessing (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Something along the lines of:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from os import cpu_count

with Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:
    pool.map(func, list(df.itertuples()))
```

Where `func` is the function your applying to generate the row from the original row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I end up writing csv row by row and then reading it as a dataframe. Much faster.